# Printer settings in Ubuntu and Ubuntu Studio versus printer settings in Linux Mint

Tags: printing, epson, photo

I am a longtime Linux Mint (10+ years) user and I like the detail settings when printing photos in Mint. I am considering shifting to Ubuntu Studio. I do not see the opportunity for detailed printer settings in Ubuntu and Studio.

Print quality in Ubuntu is just like good or bad. Mint has like 10 settings about DPI going from 380 to 5760. And eight settings from economy to Best. Choice for matte or Photo black.  In Ubuntu no really possibility for paper choice and picture placement on the page.  I am a very basic user, very seldom I use a terminal.
Using Epson printers, which by the way install themselves in Mint. Also by network.

```
Drivers and connection.
usb://EPSON/SC-P600%20Series?serial=554E37593031393185
Epson SureColor P600 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.3.3
```

**Question:** Can I have the same interface in Ubuntu Studio as I have in Linux mint?

Comment: `Mint has like 10 settings about DPI going from 380 to 5760.` Can you post a screenshot of the print  settings in Linux Mint?

Comment: Just a quick reminder: please be nice to New contributors...

Comment: Have been offline a while. Have seen Is it OK to post pictures here or will I PM to archisman-panigrahi?

Answer (score 4):

Install proprietary Epson drivers from https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

and you'll have all settings.

Probably Mint installs them by default. Ubuntu also used to have these drivers in official repos. For some reason Gutenprint is installed that may lack some features.

Comment: > for some reason Gutenprint is installed. < Probably some kind of closed-source restrictions or such that prevent this.  Normally such stuff would be in restricted or multiverse, but would be contributed by Epson.  if Epson doesn't package the drivers, then that explains some stuff.

Comment: I actually set up print queues with the Epson and Gutenprint PPDs, Anyone following in my footsteps would see that the Epson PPD does not provide the options described by @drfihl.

Answer (score 1):

Install the same driver on Ubuntu Studio as you have on Mint and set up a print queue with it. You want the **printer-driver-gutenprint** package.

Comment: @drfihl has two choices. He cannot be bothered to say if one or the other (if either) suits him. Yet another askubuntu leading nowhere.